# I'm stuck on this logical program for days. can someone help me figure it out?

Tags: java, logic

A Challenge

Input : Standard Input 
Output : Standard Output 
Time Limit : 3 sec
It is another sunday evening at codecity and as usual a lot of coding challenges are being announced.Our hero Bob finds that one of the challenge is really intresting and gives a try.The challenge is that Given two Integers A and B, Bob should find out the numbers in the range [A...B] inclusive that contains no digit which occurs more than twice in it.Write a computer program for Bob to solve this challenge.

Input:
The first line contains the number of test cases T. Each of the next T lines contains two integers, A and B.

Output:
Output T lines, one for each case containing the required answer for the corresponding case

Constraints:

1 <= T <= 10000
1 <= A <= B <= 108
Sample Input:

3
100 120
1000 1000
123 456
Sample Output:

20
0
331
Explanation: 
For the first case, all numbers except 111 satisfy the condition.

Comment: ...what have you tried?

Comment: i'm not able to figure out the logic.

Comment: i have tried using for loop. But i am not able to understand "inclusive that contains no digit which occurs more than twice in it" this particularly!

Comment: Why is the answer 20 if he should find out the numbers? 101 seems like a valid number. Or should he find out how many numbers from the range?

Comment: maybe you can paste some code, so we can see where you have gone wrong

Comment: @Daniel He is asking for the how many numbers thing!

Comment: i'm a noob at this :/

Comment: SO can't help you become less of a novice, only hard work and persistence on your part can.

Comment: I didn't even ask u to help me out on that part! :)

Comment: And FYI I'm just 13! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I've also added the reading from standard IO in the main. The solution should be complete now, except from the requirements, which you can also built in. I've commented it, so you know what's going on. It may not be the most efficient/elegant solution, so improvements are welcome:

```
public static int getNumbers(int a, int b){
    //Return if invalid input
    if(b < a){
        return -1;
    }

    int counter = 0;

    //Iterate over all numbers from the range
    for(int i = a; i <= b; ++i){
        boolean validNumber = true;

        //List of digits - we will put how many we have in here
        int[] digits = new int[10];

        //Split the number into digits
        int number = i;
        while(number > 0){
             //Get current digit
             int currentDigit = number % 10;
             //Increment the number of these digits found
             ++digits[currentDigit];
             //If number greater than 4, set flag and break loop
             if(digits[currentDigit] > 2){
                 validNumber = false;
                 break;
             }
             //Divide by 10 to get the next digit
             number = number / 10;
        }
        //Ig the number is valid, increase counter
        if(validNumber == true){
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

The code from the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getNumbers(100, 120));
    System.out.println(getNumbers(1000, 1000));
    System.out.println(getNumbers(123, 456));

    //Invalid input test case
    System.out.println(getNumbers(20, 10));


    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Number of test cases: ");
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Please Enter A: ");
        int a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Please Enter B: ");
        int b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(getNumbers(a, b));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //TODO: Treat this!!!!
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO: Treat this!!!!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The output:

```
20
0
331
-1
Please Enter The Number of test cases: 
1
Please Enter A: 
100
Please Enter B: 
120
20
```

By the way, I don't get this requirement: 1 <= A <= B <= 104. Amend to your code or post a comment.

Comment: Thank you! :) ur code did help me understand the logic better. I was later corrected that constraint was 10^8 and not 10^4. Anyways I edited that part and got it done. Thanks for ur efforts :)

Comment: You're welcome, @AnkitPanchal. Glad I could help. BTW: I made my first program in Delphi when I was 13, so keep it up, you're on the right track!

Comment: Lol! I wish to become like you all one day, solving any challenge in minutes. *inspired* :)